# Python with SQLite. SQLite data into variable

Tags: python, sqlite, printing, screen, output

SQLite in python, print it on screen, python 3.2.4

I have this code

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Player")
while True:

    row = cur.fetchone()
    print(row)
    print("why  {0}".format(cur.fetchone()))

    if row == None:
        break
```

and i receive this output:
Load from databases

```
    (1, 'Damian', 1, 15, 18, 100, 100)
    why  None
    None
    why  None
```

((( (1, 'Damian', 1, 15, 18, 100, 100)   )) <-- this is in my database. why when i try to print out in another print it doesnt works ? or when i try to print like this : print(row[0]) it shows error like =
print(row[0])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: `row` is `None` on the second loop, so it has no first element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are calling `fetchone()` two times inside the loop.
There is nothing magical about the `while` loop that corresponds to rows; instead it is a side effect of the call to `fetchone()` that advances to the next result row.

The first `print` outputs the first row; the second (with `"why"`) would print the second row (if it existed).